# Where to use CORBA and Where to use SNMP for monitoring?

Tags: networking, snmp, corba, telecommunication

I am new to telecom domain. Can anybody please help me to understand where to use CORBA and where to use SNMP for network monitoring(NMS/EMS). How it interacts with OSS systems for monitoring(fault and perfomance).

Answer (score 1):

1. SNMP is usually used to monitor devices directly from NMS/OSS "point-to-point".
2. The CORBA is usually used as so called "northbound" interface when you need to
   integrate NMS/OSS with vendor specific EMS. There are protocols like
   TMF814, 3GPP that work on top of CORBA.